# How can I increase the size of crashkernel/issues when setting up kdump

Tags: kernel, vmware

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running in VMware Fusion 8.1.0. I'm trying to learn how to write device drivers and am trying to set up up my development environment.

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html) to set up kdump, but whenever I try to test the crash dump mechanism with `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, the system hangs.

Searching has told me that the issue is probably that my crashkernel size is too small (though the memory is 2 GB and the system has set aside 128MB). I'm trying to follow the directions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe#Troubleshooting), but when I go to `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, I can't find "crashkernel" anywhere (so I can't edit the parameter).

What am I doing wrong and how can I change the crashkernel size? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The file configuration file you're looking for is actually in `/etc/default/grub.d/kexec-tools.cfg`. Just modify that file and change `crashkernel` to:

```
crashkernel=<xxx>M
```

Then run:

```
update-grub
```

And reboot.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed using sudo apt install linux-crashdump

Then change here

/etc/default/grub.d/kdump-tools.cfg

Comment: can you add details on exactly what needs changing in this file?